# Create a tensor variable of given length in Theano functions

Tags: numpy, parallel-processing, theano

For example:

```
x = tensor.scalar()
ret = give_me_zeros_of_length(x)
my_zeros = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=ret)
my_zeros(4)  # should get [0 0 0 0]
```

What is the best way to do this *give_me_zeros_of_length* in Theano?
Thank you in advance.

Edit:
So I've answered my own question, the answer is written clearly in the Theano tutorial document. Lazy me.

Comment: Might it be sufficcient to do

    ret = [0.0] * x

Comment: @s1h I tried, but x is of type tensor.scalar, so it only outputs [0]. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the tensor.alloc() function from [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#creating-tensor)

```
x = tensor.scalar(dtype="int32")
ret = tensor.alloc(0, x)
my_zeros = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=ret)
my_zeros(5)  # gives [0 0 0 0 0]
```

Note that by default the `alloc` function will take 0 as of type int8, can use `numpy.int32(0)` to convert it into a 32-bit 0.